# Response coming from Volley the first time only

Tags: android, json, web-services, android-volley

I'm using Volley to fetch data from server. I have 2 activities, Activity A and B. Both uses Volley and the same Request Queue via a Singleton to fetch data. Everything works fine in Activity A, and when I start Activity B I get Volley's response.

The problem is, if I finish from activity B and move to A, and then start B again, Volley seems to fail to get a response. What am I doing wrong?

My Singleton

```
public class CustomVolleyRequestQueue {

    private static CustomVolleyRequestQueue mInstance;
    private static Context mCtx;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    private CustomVolleyRequestQueue(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
        mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new LruBitmapCache(
                LruBitmapCache.getCacheSize(mCtx)));
    }

    public static synchronized CustomVolleyRequestQueue getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new CustomVolleyRequestQueue(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(mCtx.getCacheDir(), 10 * 1024 * 1024);
            Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
            mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
            // Don't forget to start the volley request queue
            mRequestQueue.start();
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getmImageLoader(){
        return mImageLoader;
    }

}
```

My Custom request

```
public class CustomJSONObjectRequest extends JsonObjectRequest{

    private Priority mPriority;

    public CustomJSONObjectRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
                                   Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener,
                                   Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, jsonRequest, listener, errorListener);
        //this.setShouldCache(true);
    }


    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        return headers;
    }

    @Override
    public RetryPolicy getRetryPolicy() {
        // here you can write a custom retry policy
        return super.getRetryPolicy();
    }

    public void setPriority(Priority priority) {
        mPriority = priority;
    }

    @Override
    public Priority getPriority() {
        return mPriority == null ? Priority.NORMAL : mPriority;
    }

}
```

I perform and add the request on the onStart of my Activity B as follows,

```
  protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mQueue = CustomVolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext())
                .getRequestQueue();

        final CustomJSONObjectRequest jsonRequest = new CustomJSONObjectRequest(Request.Method
                .GET, url,
                new JSONObject(), this, this);

        jsonRequest.setTag(REQUEST_TAG);
        jsonRequest.setPriority(Request.Priority.HIGH);
        mQueue.add(jsonRequest);
        setupRecyclerView(rv, rv2, rv3);
    }
```

My activity B Implements the Response Listener, where I simple parse the JSON and display the data on the UI.

I've been going on about this issue for a quite while, I've learned the tips and tricks of other features of Volley, caching, Ignoring requests, going deep to play around with the library and using it with other libraries. Yet, I still fail to see what I could be doing wrong here.

Comment: Have you tried to put it inside `onResume` or `onPostResume` yet?

Comment: @BNK Nope, I figured out where I went wrong, but thanks, I would have tried that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright found my solution, and it's quite embarrassing. I was using a `static` URL to add the GET parameter. Since it was my first time using Volley, I didn't know how to add GET parameters to requests, was supposed to come back to it later on. I forgot.

So basically I am concatenating the GET parameter value the next time I move to the next activity, hence getting a null response from the server since those values don't exist there.

It was too simple to notice, I should have been more careful with my debugging.

Comment: However, digging too deep in to the matter allowed me to learn and understand the other features. So that's something.